# Default relation for Django OneToOne Field

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a couple django models with a one to one relation. However I'm trying to get it so the related one to one model is automatically created. If I have something simple like this:

```
class MyObject(models.Model):
    data = models.OneToOneField('MyData', related_name='my_object')

class MyData(models.Model):
    info = models.TextField(null=True)
```

If I create a MyObject and access MyObject.data it will return None. I was hoping there was a way I can have it return a MyData object (just default reference).

I'd like MyObject to automatically have a related MyData object. Is there a way for me to do this or do I need to check every time to see if there's a related MyData object?

Comment: do not add data MyData in single quotes
Use this


data = models.OneToOneField(MyData, related_name='my_object')

and then first create the Mydata entry and add inthe MyObject Entry and

then at the time of fetching from the database.

you can query like

MyObject.objects.filter(data=data).select_related('my_object')

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the official [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/)?

```
d = MyData(info='whatever')
o = MyObject(data=d)
```

How can it be automatic if info text field has to be filled in?

**after seeing your edit**:
you can probably set my data to be null

```
o = MyObject(data=Mydata(info=None))
```

of course, your Mydata should now be able to accept None as their type.

Comment: maybe Im not getting what you're asking. in that case you need to clarify your question a bit more.

Comment: Yes, I have. I know how to create the relationship but was hoping that MyObject.data would always return a MyData object (the info field can be null, doesn't need to be filled in) instead of None. Sorry for the ambiguity! Editing...